# Customize the imported python module

Tags: python, module, cloud, ibm-cloud, customization

I have a question about python modules. I am working on the notebook of IBM watson studio. I want to dump(deploy) a KernelDensityEstimation model as web service. But this KDE module does not has a "predict" funtion. If I want to deploy machine learning model from IBM studio, I assume they should have "predict" function. So now I wanted to add this functionality to the KernelDensity module. How can this be done? Or are there any ways to deploy this model. Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can achieve this by your own custom module by inheriting the KDE module. What you have to do is create a module and add a custom class inheriting from KernelDensity and add your own method inside that class so that you can access all the class attributes of KernelDensity

Example:

```
from sklearn.neighbors import KernelDensity

class MyKernelDensity(KernelDensity):
    def predict():
        # Your code goes here
        pass
```

After defining this, you should always import MyKernelDensity from your custom module instead of importing KernelDensity

i.e.

```
from my_module import MyKernelDensity

density = MyKernelDensity(bandwidth=bandwidth, **kwargs)
density.predict()
```

I have only provided examples, you have to rewrite this accordingly.